# 2 legged oauth for google calendar v3

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client, google-api-client, google-apps-marketplace, 2-legged

I am working with Version 3 of Google Calendar REST API(using HttpClient) and its working fine. Similarly I've to work with web APIs of V3 Google Calendar since my application is in Google Apps marketplace. How can I proceed with 2 legged OAuth in V3 Google Calendar APIs. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Riyaz Ashraf.

Comment: Post code you are working with .

Comment: @Shail I am using below code for authentication  HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory(); GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant authRequest = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant();
    authRequest.transport=TRANSPORT;
    authRequest.jsonFactory=JSON_FACTORY;
    authRequest.clientId=CLIENT_ID;
    authRequest.clientSecret=CLIENT_SECRET;
    authRequest.redirectUri=redirectUrl;
    authRequest.code=code;
    authRequest.useBasicAuthorization = false;
    AccessTokenResponse authResponse = authRequest.execute();  I got response successfully by this.

Comment: You should move away from 2-Legged OAuth to Service Accounts-based OAuth2. There is a nice writeup for [Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation), which would be similar implementing it for Calendar.

Also, please note we have released a new experience for the Google Apps Marketplace ([see announcement](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2013/11/third-party-apps-now-easier-to-find-and.html)). We also have new [Developer Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/).

Comment: Please specify if by "2-legged OAuth" you mean the same as it's described here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount or not. On this site,  "2-legged" OAuth is referred as using `service account` to act on behave of users.